# Can't Start MySQL on Mavericks

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks

I recently upgraded my Mac to Mavericks and am having trouble getting MySQL to work.

I removed my previous MySQL installation per instructions found on the web, then downloaded the DMG file and ran the installer - after which, I was able to get it running, but was not able to log in.

I noticed the installer created a /usr/local/mysql/ directory which points to /usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64

I then replaced the /usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64/data directory with the old data directory, and now I can't start MySQL.

I get the error: "warning the /usr/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the 'mysql' or '_mysql' user" and can no longer start MySQL.

I tried to change permissions of the directory with the following without luck:

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data

sudo chown -R _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

chown: /usr/local/var/mysql: No such file or directory

sudo chmod -R o+rwx /usr/local/var/mysql

chmod: /usr/local/var/mysql: No such file or directory

I did modify the plist file and cnf files as described here:

https://community.jboss.org/blogs/tedjones/2014/05/02/getting-mysql-up-and-running-after-upgrading-to-mavericks?_sscc=t

Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this problem. You just have to be meticulous when you run the install.

Please note that upgrading from Mac OS 10.8 or older to Mavericks will cause MySQL to no longer run (in other words, "Are you sure you want to upgrade to Mavericks?")

With MySQL non-functional, I decided to reinstall MySQL and upgrade to the newest version.

I followed the instructions in the link above with the following words of advice:

1. Backup your MySQL data directory before doing anything.

   The MySQL data file is located in the /usr/local/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64/data directory (or similar, depending on what version you have installed).

   BACK IT UP!
2. Make sure you stop MySQL before installing the upgraded version.

   If your plist file has keepalive set to True, every time you try to quit MySQL, it will quit (or will appear to quit) but then immediately restart.

   If you want to use the Preference Pane to start and stop MySQL, make sure you set keepalive in the .plist file to false, otherwise the Preference Pane won't work.

   I tried to kill the plist process after making the change, but it wouldn't work. I just restarted my Mac and from that point on, I was able to start and stop MySQL from Terminal or the Preference Pane when needed.

   Occasionally, the Preference Pane failed to start/stop MySQL. In that case, I would enter the start/stop command in Terminal and it worked.

   Start MySQL:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
   ```

   Stop MySQL:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
   ```
3. Download the .dmg file from MySQL and run the installer.

   I did try downloading the .tar file, and it may have worked - but on my second try, I chose the .dmg file and everything went smoothly.

   If you try to start MySQL at this point, it should run without a problem.

   Remember, since at this point you have a clean install of MySQL, you can log in with the username 'root' and password 'no password' (leave password blank).

   Please note that if you start MySQL from the terminal, you will get more information than trying from the Preference Pane, so if you are having difficulty, make sure you stop and start MySQL from Terminal. You will get some error messages that you use to troubleshoot the problem.
4. You can modify the .cnf and .plist files as mentioned in the installer instructions above (as long as you stop MySQL before making any changes).

   Typically you would copy and paste the information from the web page (mentioned above) into the .cnf file. It is pretty straight forward, but double and triple check that the copy and paste did not miss a character or two. This happened to me while pasting the code into the .cnf file (the first two characters were missing) and it took me hours to figure this out - which prevented MySQL from starting.

   If the changes to the .cnf or .plist file don't seem to take effect, restart the Mac (easier than restarting the process).
5. Moving your data.

   My install created a /usr/local/mysql/ alias or symbolic link to the /usr/local/mysql/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64 directory.

   The /usr/local/mysql/data directory (which is actually the /usr/local/mysql/mysql-5.6.19-osx10.7-x86_64/data directory - remember, it's a symbolic link) is where your data resides.

   You want a backup of your previous data directory. If you forgot to back that up before running the installer, and you have a Time Machine backup, you can retrieve it.

   The easiest way to do this is to open the /usr/local/ directory (From the Finder and choose "Go to Folder" from the Go menu) and with the /usr/local/ directory open in the Finder, choose Enter Time Machine from the Time Machine menu. Go back to the last known date that has your previous MySQL installation. Find the folder of your previous MySQL install and open the data directory.

   You have to choose all the files from the exact same point in time. You can't choose one data folder from one day and one data folder from another (I actually did this and spent a lot of time trying to figure out why one of my data tables were visible in Sequel Pro but wouldn't work). After a while, I finally figured out that everything absolutely has to be from the exact same point in time.

   You can copy files while in Time Machine by right-clicking on them. Choose all your data folders (with the .ibd and .frm files in them) PLUS all the ib_logfiles (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1), auto.cnf, and the .pid file. Basically copy everything in the mysql data folder EXCEPT the mysql, performance_schema, and test directories.

   Exit Time Machine.

   Make sure MySQL is stopped and then paste the data files into the /usr/local/mysql/data directory.
6. Set the privileges to the data directory.

   In Terminal, enter:

   ```
   sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
   ```

   Make sure NOT to use the chmod 777 command as some people online said it can damage things.
7. Now, start MySQL and you should have your data files from your previous MySQL install intact and functional. In addition, I did not have to reset any passwords for Sequel Pro. The Sequel Pro settings saved before the Mavericks upgrade worked.

Comment: Thanks however I just had to run sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data then restart the server :)

Comment: Same as @Jon 

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data 

helped!